# Vue $watch for array of objects

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I am new to Vue. We are migrating code from dojo to Vue. I was trying to add watch to an Array of objects. My data in which I have to add watch is an array of objects and Objects again can have arrays.

Sample data:

```
    ‘ItemList’: [
    {
    ‘item’: {
    ‘term’: ‘1’,
    ‘timing’:‘A’
    ‘steps’: [{}], ( Array )
    ‘parameter’: [{}] ( Array)
    …
    …

    almost 600 values
    }
    },
    {
    ‘item’: {
    ‘term’: ‘2’,
    ‘timing’:‘B’
    ‘steps’: [{}],
    ‘parameter’: [{}]

    ....
    ....

    almost 600 values
    }
    }
    ]
```

In old dojo the code was like this:

```
    for (c = 0; c < itemList.length; c++) {
       item=itemList[c];
       var itemWatch = item.watch(function(name,oldVal,newVal) {
       }
    }

//Here the name gives what value of array is changed . I need that for future 
//logic. we can add  watch on each item.

    computed:{
      clonedItems: function(){
                         return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.itemList));
                      }     
                },
                 watch:{

                    clonedItems:{
                              deep: true,
                              handler: function (val, oldVal) {
```

This I tried which is working fine, but to get to know what value is changed of this will be heavy computation. This array can be of 100 items and each item have 600  items where we have arrays as well.

Please  guide what is the best way to achieve the similar functionality what we have.

Comment: Watchers are more problematic when it comes to performance. Ask yourself whether you really need a watcher or whether you can simply put a handler on an event and take the changed value you need, in this way you are not "subscribing" to a large object rather only computing once. 
If it is specific changes you need then you may want to look at computed properties.
Also the changed value is simply `val`, you already have it!

Comment: Hi.I need to update a status on any chnage made to all the fiels. so i thought watcher will be good option. Yes  I have the changed array but i want to know which element(index) of the array is changed atleast. To get the diff  between val and oldVal  will be very excessive as it is array of items and each item have almost 600 values( which includes the array also). It will make the process very slow. Any suggestion where the watch can be done in loop so that we have the index.